# multi-vendor CS-Cart admin panel access throws error after new hosting migration

Tags: authentication, migration, admin, cs-cart

my multi-vendor website migrated to the new hosting provider and I can no longer access to admin panel as it throws an error. Their migration team unable to locate the error :( I am not a developer guys, is there anyone who have any ideas on how to resolve this thing???

This page isn’t working

......com is currently unable to handle this request.

HTTP ERROR 500

I also managed to get the screenshot of debug , not sure if it makes any sense to anyone.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x6oIj.png)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the delete the `/var/cache` folder, and visit the admin page using the `cc` and `ctpl` query parameters. So, `mystore.com/admin.php?cc&ctpl`, if you have `admin5.php`, it would become `mystore.com/admin5.php?cc&cptl`.